# Point multiplication in elliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose $a$ is an integer and $Q$ is a point on an elliptic curve and $(x,y)$ are $x$ and $y$ coordinates of this point.
My question is:
Whether $a\cdot Q$ is equal to $(ax, ay)$?

Comment: In general, $(ax, ay)$ isn't even on the curve.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. See how the addition on a elliptic curve is motivated by geometry: Adding $P$ and $Q$ is done by finding the third point of intersection between the line through $P$ and $Q$ and the curve, then reflecting at the $x$-axis. For $P+P$ you take the tangent at $P$, find the second intersection point and reflect that. This will in general not coincide with just adding the coordinates.

This is illustrated in the [Wikipedia article on Elliptic Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law).